# What is the type for "$axios" in Nuxt.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

### Summery

Now I implemented `RepositoryFactory` pattern for API connection.
https://medium.com/canariasjs/vue-api-calls-in-a-smart-way-8d521812c322 
In `repository.ts`, I wrote `$axios`.

```
import testRepository from '~/api/testRepository'

export interface Repositories {
  hoge: testRepository 
}

export default function ({ $axios }, inject) { # <- error on $axios
  const hoge = new testRepository ($axios)
  const repositories: Repositories = {
    hoge
  }
  inject('repositories', repositories)
}
```

But it show error message `Binding element '$axios' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)`.
I want to know what is the correct type for `$axios`

### What I've tried

`{ $axios } : any` can resolve it, but I want to know exact type for '$axios'.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add @nuxt/types and @nuxtjs/axios in your tsconfig.json file?
If you need more information, you can look at: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/axios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's already added.

Comment: @jpskgc Ok. Just checking. Generally you can import some types from axios like: 
import { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, AxiosStatic } from 'axios'
In your case, I guess you're looking for "AxiosResponse".
I'm not sure but if you have the types set in tsconfig file, you don't need to use import. You have it globally.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Nuxt2 and above solution didn't work for me, this is the way I am using it without any problem.

```
this.$axios.$post
```

I am uncertain if this is the best practice, but at least works without any type problem.